# Show or hide a div based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html select

```
 <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field
 CodeSetup must be a number." id="CodeSetup" name="CodeSetup">
<option selected="selected" value="0">AllCodes</option>   
<option value="1">ClientCodes</option>
<option value="2">EmployeeClass</option>
</select>

<div id="eeclass">
      <div class="row setup-code-edit">
       <label class="control-label col-md-5 label-blue-small" for="EEClassCodes">EEClassCodes</label>
         <div class="col-md-7">
  <input class="form-control" id="EEClassCodes" name="EEClassCodes" type="text" value="">
         <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="EEClassCodes" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have a div with a field that needs to be displayed when a certain option is shown

```
<input class="form-control" id="EEClassCodes" name="EEClassCodes" type="text" value="">
```

The script I am running looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#eeclass').hide();
        $("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
            $('#eeclass').show();
        });

    })
```

This shows the hidden field on select but doesn't do it specifically for when someone selects the EmployeeClass option (value="2").  It just shows it regardless of change.

I also need it to hide the field when the value is deselected.  Would a toggle be good here? i tried toggling but didn't seem to have it right.

Comment: Where's `$('#eeclass')` in your example?

Comment: `if (this.value == 2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want only to show it when value of the select is `2`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#eeclass').hide();
        $("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
            if($(this).val() == 2) {
               $('#eeclass').show();
            } else {
               $('#eeclass').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
            }
        });

    })
```

Comment: Sorry, I just typed the wrong word, yes, I ment show ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you want toggle. Have a go with

```
$("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
  $('#eeclass').toggle($(this).val()==2); // or this.value==2
});
```

Comment: Not sure if it's really a performance issue, but wouldn't `this.value==2` be simpler?

Comment: Yeah.  Very negligible.  I can't see this being put into a loop.  I honestly don't know if using the value property is useful in any way.  Does `val()` just return the value property or is there more to it like data sanitization or whatever?

Comment: I Very often use this.id instead of $(this).attr("id") or $(this).prop("id") simply because it is easier to read. But I stick to .val() if I use jQuery to get values

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field
     CodeSetup must be a number." id="CodeSetup" name="CodeSetup">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">AllCodes</option>   
    <option value="1" data-div="eeclass0">ClientCodes</option>
    <option value="2" data-div="eeclass1">EmployeeClass</option>
    </select>
```

and javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.EEClassCodes').hide();
        $("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
            $ ( '#'+$(this).attr('data-div') ).show();
        });

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide it every time the select changes (in case the user selected 2 and then changed their minds to select 1), and then if the selection is 2, show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eeclass').hide();
    $("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
        $('#eeclass').hide(); //always hide on change
        if($(this).val() == 2) {
             $('#eeclass').show(); //show only if value is 2
        }
    });
});
```

or hide on else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eeclass').hide();
    $("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
        if($(this).val() == 2) {
             $('#eeclass').show(); //show if value is 2
        }
        else {
            $('#eeclass').hide(); //hide if value is not 2
        }
    });
});
```

I would say either case is okay, but can be debated.

Comment: In case it's already shown. You could hide on else, but I could see pros and cons for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this

### HTML

```
      <head>
        <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <select name="CodeSetup" id="CodeSetup" data-val-number="The field
     CodeSetup must be a number." data-val="true" class="form-control">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">AllCodes</option>
          <option value="1">ClientCodes</option>
          <option value="2">EmployeeClass</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" value="" name="EEClassCodes" id="EEClassCodes" class="form-control" />
      </body>

    </html>
```

### scrpit.js (js)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#EEClassCodes').hide();

      $("#CodeSetup").change(function(){
            if(parseInt($(this).val()) === 2){
              $('#EEClassCodes').show();
            }
            else{
              $('#EEClassCodes').hide();
            }
      });


    })
```