# Show or hide div based on selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to JQuery and I want to make a simple function. I have a div that is named based on an id of a checkbox. I want the div to be shown only if its checkbox is checked but the code is not working. It show me this error ($courseTimeDiv.hide is not a function).

this is the part where I define the checkbox

```
`$programList .= ' <div class="form-check proDiv">
 <input type="checkbox" name="course[]"  class="form-check-input group2" 
 id="'.$coursePrice.'" value="'.$courseId.'">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="'.$coursePrice.'">'.$courseName .' 
 price is '.$coursePrice.'$</label>
 </div>';`
```

this is the part of HTML code where I define the div

```
` $programList .= '<div name="timeDiv'.$courseId.'" class="timeGroup" >            
                   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timeRadio" 
                    value="Weekday" name="time['.$courseId.']" />
                    <label class="form-check-label"><strong>Weekdays</strong> 
                    </div> </div>';
                               `
```

and this is the JQuery code

```
`$("input[name='course[]']").on('change', function () {
      
      var  $courseIdValue = $('input[name="course[]"]:checked').val(); 

      var  $courseTimeDiv =  $("input[name='timeDiv']") + $courseIdValue;

        if($courseTimeDiv.match(/$courseIdValue/)) {
            $courseTimeDiv.show(300);
            } 
            else {
              $courseTimeDiv.hide();
            }
      });`
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show or hide a div based on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414758/show-or-hide-a-div-based-on-selection)

Comment: There are a bunch of questions like questions that have answers.  Please search for `[javascript][jQuery] show or hide div`

Comment: @Tibrogargan .Thanks for your reply. Yes I know there are a lot of answers and I searched a lot but I didn't find one that works for me .. because my div name is not static .. its name is based on the checkbox name and I think this is the problem in my code

Comment: What are you using to generate the HTML, that isn't plain HTML? Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: So really, your question should be "how do I get the name of a checkbox".  There are also dozens of questions like that.

Comment: Your selectors will not work, especially since you're doing "select all elements of type input where name = x" and a `div` is not an `input`, especially since the `name` property is only applicable to input elements, it's meaningless on a `div`.  Use `id`

Comment: @JonP I am using PHP to get the courses' ids from the DB and set the ids to be a value for each checkbox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`var  $courseTimeDiv =  $("input[name='timeDiv']") + $courseIdValue;`

what are you trying to do in this line?

IF, you're trying to select an element, then you can't use `match` method on it in the next line

IF, you're trying to create element's selector, then js engine is right and your variable does not have an element so you can select it

and in both scenarios you're doing it wrong because you're selecting an input element with name='timeDiv'+blabla while in your code there is no such element

I believe you meant

```
   var selector = "div.timeDiv" + $courseIdValue
   var  $courseTimeDiv =  $(selector);
```

it's not this simple
you have multiple checkboxes and each checkbox has it's own value, and you want all the selected ones

so
you need to process them to see which one is selected and which one is not, and match method won't help you in this process

```
`$("input[name*='course']").on('change', function () {

      var  value = $(this).val();
      var  selector = "div[name*=[timeDiv" + value + "]" 
      var  courseTimeDiv =  $(selector);
      
      if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
          courseTimeDiv.show(300);
      } else {
          courseTimeDiv.hide();
      }
  });`
```

I think this should work!

=========UPDATE==========

Previous code works, but it can be wrote in this way to have better performance

```
`$("input[name*='course']").on('change', function () {

      var  value = this.value;
      var  selector = "div[name*=[timeDiv" + value + "]" 
      var  courseTimeDiv =  $(selector);
      
      if( this.checked ){
          courseTimeDiv.show(300);
      } else {
          courseTimeDiv.hide();
      }
  });`
```

Comment: Keep the personal comments out of the answers please.  This can be simplified to `$(function() {$('input.form-check-input').on('change', function() {$( \`#timeDiv${this.value}\` ).toggle() }) })
`

Comment: well you're right about personal comments, sorry, I've deleted those parts,, but about your code, nope it's not correct, because the div his trying to select does not have any id attribute, he's trying to select it by name attribute ! but yes it's more simple

Comment: `div` elements don't get names.  He needs to use some other selector.  `id` would be easiest, since each div will be unique to based on the course id.

Comment: div elements CAN get name attribute (just tested it to make sure), however you're basically right, it's not appropriate for a div element to have 'name' attr, I wrote my answer based on his case

Comment: Yes.  You can pretty much put a `name` property on anything you want in JavaScript.  Doesn't mean it's going to work as expected.

Comment: yes you just said what I said in other words, it's possible but not good!

Comment: `var value = $(this).val()` is a more expensive version of `this.value`.  Same for `$(this).is(':checked')`.  Use `this.checked`.

Comment: Absolutely right, using jQuery is on depreciation just because of these unnecessary costs, VanillaJS(aka pure js) is much better

Comment: jQuery is great for some things, but it's not the for everything.  Use it when you get value our of doing so, don't use it when you don't.  Trying to help you improve your answer here.

Comment: Well you're right, I'll update the answer, Tnx